# Regular expression for dd/mm

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Please help me with a regular expression to validate the following format

```
dd/mm
```

This is for validating a Birthday field and the year is not required.

Thanks

Comment: What programming language/regex engine are you using?  Please update your tags/question title to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool foundMatch = false;
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, 
    @"^(?:
     (?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:0?2|Feb(?:ruary)?)
     |
     (?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/
      (?:
       (?:0?[469]|11)
       |
       Apr(?:il)?|June?|Sep(?:tember)?|Nov(?:ember)?
      )
     |
     (?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/
      (?:
       (?:0?[13578]|1[02])
       |
       Jan(?:uary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|May|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Dec(?:ember)?
      )
     )$",  
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

will match valid days/months. It will always match Feb 29 since it doesn't know the year.

By the way, I made this regex using [RegexMagic](http://www.regexmagic.com) (much too tedious to do this manually - another sign that this is rather a job for a date/time parser).

Comment: Thanks Tim. How easy will it be to change the format from mm/dd to mm/month i.e 02/febraury etc?

Comment: Now both variants are supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Regex(@"^\d{2}/\d{2}$")
```

or:

```
new Regex(@"^\d\d/\d\d$")
```

`\d` represents a digit, and `{2}` specifies that it must be repeated twice.

To check if it's a real date, use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
DateTime date;
bool valid;
valid = DateTime.TryParseExact("00/00", "dd/MM", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date); // false
valid = DateTime.TryParseExact("30/02", "dd/MM", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date); // false
valid = DateTime.TryParseExact("27/02", "dd/MM", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date); // true
```

However, this will not handle leap years properly.  Probably the best solution is to ask for the year of birth after all.

Comment: in this regular expression 00/00 is a valid date

Comment: @Itay, she asked about validating the format, not that it was a real date.  To check if it's a real date, it's best just to use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Matthew ... Its She not her ;-)

Comment: How can I validate date as well. For example .. 30/02 should be false.

Comment: You cannot validate a date if you do not have the year because you cant tell if February 29 is valid or not

Comment: yeah yeah .. I know... 29 can be an exemption.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])$
```

but this one will allow for example 30/02